# Retrofit error URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

Делаю такой запрос

> @GET("v2/search?lang=en&portal="+PORTAL_ID+"&type=course&query={query}&start=0")
>       Call getSearchResult(@Path("query") String query);

выдает ошибку что Retrofit error URL query string must not have replace block.
Я и @Path и @Query пробовал. все равно эту ошибку выдает.
Я хочу заменить {query} на полученную переменную

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Просто уберите `query={query}`. И `Path` поменяйте на  `@Query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Аннотация @Path предназначена для параметров функции, которые заменяют часть пути URL https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html

> Named replacement in a URL path segment. Values
>   are converted to strings using Retrofit.stringConverter(Type,
>   Annotation[]) (or Object.toString(), if no matching string converter
>   is installed) and then URL encoded. Simple example:
>
> @GET("/image/{id}")  Call example(@Path("id") int id);
>
> Calling with foo.example(1) yields /image/1.

В вашем случае query - это параметр запроса, а не часть пути, поэтому для него нужно использовать аннотацию @Query https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

> Query parameter appended to the URL. Values are converted to strings
>   using Retrofit.stringConverter(Type, Annotation[]) (or
>   Object.toString(), if no matching string converter is installed) and
>   then URL encoded. null values are ignored. Passing a List or array
>   will result in a query parameter for each non-null item.
>
> Simple Example:
>
> @GET("/friends")  Call friends(@Query("page") int
>   page);
>
> Calling with foo.friends(1) yields /friends?page=1.

А из @GET(...) query нужно убрать

```
@GET("v2/search?lang=en&portal="+PORTAL_ID+"&type=course&start=0")
Call getSearchResult(@Query("query") String query);
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, Теперь буду знать